# CUDA Installation issue on Ubuntu 16.04 due to unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management

I am trying install cuda on ubuntu 16.04. Have followed the below steps to do so.

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-2-local_9.2.148-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-<version>/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

However, I am getting the below error when executing the last line.

> """Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies: cuda : Depends: cuda-9-2 (>= 9.2.148) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.""""

Not exactly sure where the issue is. I also tried uninstalling and deleting older version but still no success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)